# Azure app registration Quickstart code producing ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, visual-studio-2019

Downloading and running the Quickstart code for .NET Core in from my app registration in the Azure AD web portal is producing a `ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` in my browser when accessing the index page of the app.

This is set up as a single tenant app.

Code files below with secrets redacted. If you need to know about any further config just ask.

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "[Enter the domain of your tenant, e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com]",
    "TenantId": "XXXXXXX",
    "ClientId": "XXXXXXX",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";

                // Per the code below, this application signs in users in any Work and School
                // accounts and any Microsoft Personal Accounts.
                // If you want to direct Azure AD to restrict the users that can sign-in, change 
                // the tenant value of the appsettings.json file in the following way:
                // - only Work and School accounts => 'organizations'
                // - only Microsoft Personal accounts => 'consumers'
                // - Work and School and Personal accounts => 'common'

                // If you want to restrict the users that can sign-in to only one tenant
                // set the tenant value in the appsettings.json file to the tenant ID of this
                // organization, and set ValidateIssuer below to true.

                // If you want to restrict the users that can sign-in to several organizations
                // Set the tenant value in the appsettings.json file to 'organizations', set
                // ValidateIssuer, above to 'true', and add the issuers you want to accept to the
                // options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers collection
                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
            });

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you clicked quickstart there was a button before the download code sample saying configure your application in azure portal (configure for me) button. did you click that? you need to click that to set up the proper redirect urls before you run the sample.

I just tested it with the following steps, create app registration, clicking authentication, adding platform, click asp.net core, clicked quickstart, clicked step 1 button, which opened a window on the right, click confirm/add, then click step 2 download, then extract files, and open in visual studio. then click run. and it worked right away.

Comment: Clicked that button previously and the step now says "Your application is configured with these attributes.". There are redirect URIs set up for `https://localhost:44321/signin-oidc` and `https://localhost:44321/`. The logout URI is set up as `https://localhost:44321/signout-oidc`. I've checked the set up in the Visual Studio project and the port number matches up for HTTPS

Comment: i dug a bit more, found this: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20105 I bet you have the latest preview of windows 10. seems to be an issue with the OS itself. need to downgrade to non latest win 10?

Comment: Don't think I'm running the latest preview? I've checked my PC settings and it's Windows 10 Pro version 1903 (Build 18362.175)